# Stream bytes from s3 to an output stream (client) and to cache server at the same time

Tags: java, caching, amazon-s3, iostream

I am trying to stream images from s3 to the client (through StreamingOutput) and to the cache server. Currently I have sth like this :

1. in-memery byte array which will be sent as input stream to a function which sends data to cache server

> final ByteArrayOutputStream cacheStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>   // caching

1. StreamingOutput stream which will be sent as the response body to client.

> ```
> StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void write(OutputStream clientStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
>                     OutputStream resultStream = new TeeOutputStream(clientStream, cacheStream);
>                     StreamUtils.copy(s3InputStream, resultStream);
>                     s3InputStream.close();
>                 }
>             };
> ```

My problem : I do not want to hold anything in memery, so stream to both client and cache with one s3 read.
I know that TeeInputStream could help but cant figure out how. Appreciate any thoughts :)

UPDATE :

For those who are interested,

```
StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream clientStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                    final InputStream wrappedInputStream = new TeeInputStream(s3InputStream, clientStream);
                    try {
                       //As soon as we write to cache, the respond also is streamed to client
                       cache.put(..., wrappedInputStream);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        //Handle this
                    } finally {
                        s3InputStream.close();
                        wrappedInputStream.close();
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: How can you give data to the cache server? Could you use a TeeInputStream to wrap the s3InputStream and the OutputStream you want to write to for client? Then give the cache server the input stream. As it reads the input stream the data is also written to the client.

Comment: Wrapping the s3Stream to TeeInputStream did the trick. Thanks. Since you asked, if the cache server does not exists, I simply stream to local file, otherwise set the stream as HttpPut's content and stream to cache server.